# Removing a spot from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
( 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Super Widget
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Amazing Widget
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Even more amazing widget
        )
)
```

How would I remove The Array at spot [1] for example? and I suppose it would have to move the array in spot [2] up to spot [1].

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove an element given its key, use

```
unset($array[$key]);
```

In your case, `$key` would be `1`.

This will leave a "hole" in the sequence of keys. You can perform an automatic reindexing of your array to get rid of that hole with

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: Figured it out, it's because I was passing the "deleteWhich" variable as a $_GET variable and I wasn't using the isset()

Answer (score 2):

```
$array[1] = $array[2];
unset($array[2]);
```

Comment: What if there are 42 elements total in the array?

Comment: This was not one of the hypotheses :)

Comment: If someone asks how to write a function that adds `$x = 1` and `$y = 2`, you do not usually reply with `function add($x, $y) { return 3; }` I hope ;-)

Comment: If someone ever asks that, actually, I think I will.